# Flutter error: Argument type 'Future<void>' can't be assigned to the parameter type '() → void'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to call the showDatePicker widget once an icon button is clicked, however when i call the onTap method get the following error:

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type '() → void'.

Please find my code below:

showDatePicker code

```
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2018, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
  }
```

IconButton code

```
    IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.date_range),
        onPressed: _selectDate(context)),
```

I'm using the StatefulWidget, please do let me know how to solve this issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are calling `_selectDate` directly, instead of passing a function that calls `_selectDate`.

Change your `onPressed` to `onPressed: (){_selectDate(context);}`